# MySql Query Browser Updating row issue

Tags: mysql

I am unable to edit my table in MySqL Query Browser.

I have the primary key defined, but I am still unable to edit.

Is there anything else that I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- does your user have write access to this table?
- does the primary key column is shown in your query?
- does your query is showing fields present in only one table?

Comment: The answer to all those 3 questions is yes